# Twitter hovercard follow button error - Response from Twitter

Tags: twitter-oauth

I'm having trouble figuring out why my follow button doesn't work on my hovercard when I mouse over the twitter icon in the header of my website?

http://followworks.com

Gone thru the application settings at twitter.com and everything looks good. Not exactly sure if it's an issue with twitter but I know other sites using hovercard work fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=J5ImMXqTZI7npE7y7WUquA&v=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">twttr.anywhere(function(T){T.hovercards();T(".twitter a, .author").hovercards({username:function(node){return node.title;}});});</script>
</head>

<body>
<li class="twitter"><a class="twitterlink" href="http://twitter.com/followworks" title="@followworks" rel="external">@followworks</a></li>
```

The code above is what I have in the page, hovercard displays properly but if you try to click follow button... twitter says ERROR!

Not a great problem to have when your business name is Follow Works and your follow button doesn't work. LOL :)

I've click the follow button logged into twitter as other users... same problem. Weirdness?

Comment: This is actually a real twitter api development problem and I didn't do this to get more followers... really. Mouse over the twitter image in the header from the link above, click follow then unfollow me if it works! Still doesn't work though from what I can tell.

Comment: This is the error I get from twitter testing with other twitter accounts, Something is technically wrong.

Thanks for noticing—we're going to fix it up and have things back to normal soon.

Comment: I've gone thru the @anywhere app settings with a fine tooth comb and can't figure out why its bugging?

Comment: Is anyone getting that same error?

Comment: Try creating a new Twitter application and using that client_id.